# computing a quadratic programming problem arising in non-linear SVM

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, quadratic-programming

According to Wikipedia, we need to solve a [specific quadratic programming problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support-vector_machine)  in order to use the SVM algorithm with kernels.
I would like to solve this quadratic problem using a python library called [CVXOPT](https://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.867/wiki/images/a/a7/Qp-cvxopt.pdf), but this routine needs the following form :

**minimise** :
$1/2 x^T P x + q^T x$

subject to :
$ Gx \leq h$ and $Ax=b$

in the context of support-vector machine, I have to solve the following quadratic problem :

**maximise** : $$f(c_1,...,c_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i - \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n y_i c_i k(x_i,x_j) y_j c_j$$

subject to : $\sum_{i=1}^n c_i y_i =0$ and $0 \leq c_i \leq \frac{1}{2 n \lambda}$ for all i.

In this context k() is a positive definite kernel function.

I don't know hot to put my second form into the form needed by CVXOPT.
Can you help me ?
Precisely, what would be $P,q,G,h,A,b$ in this context ?

Comment: You are missing another occurrence of $c_i$ in the double sum. Otherwise it is not a quadratic program.

Comment: thank you it is corrected

Comment: I deleted it just now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First difference: cvxopt  takes in a minimization problem but you are having a maximumzation problem. This can be resolved by multiplying $-1$ to the maximization objective function.

$P$ describes the quadratic part, Hence let $P_{ij}=y_ik(x_i, x_j)y_j$. The linear objective part is $q\in \mathbb{R}^n$ where $q_i = -1$.

Next let's move on to the inequality constraint, which consists of $c_i \le \frac1{2n\lambda}$ and $-c_i \le 0$. Hence, we can let $G=\begin{bmatrix} I \\ -I\end{bmatrix}$. As an exercise, can you try to write down the corresponding $h$?

$b=0$. As an exercise, can you write down the vector $A$?

Comment: thank you for your clear answer. I would say that in this context :   A is the diagonal matrix of size n*n with the $y_i$ on the diagonal. and h would be in the form of $h= \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{2n \lambda}\\\frac{1}{2n \lambda} \\ ... \\ 0\\ 0\\...\\ 0  \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: great attempt, your $h$ is correct. The size of $A$ should be $\mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$, give it another try to write down the vector?

Comment: I would say that it is simply $[y_1,y_2,...,y_n]$ ? I don't see why it is a n+1 sized vector and not just a n sized vector.

Comment: oops, I made a mistake $A$ should be $1 \times n$ and your answer is correct. congrats.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help !